# Select Articles that aren't tagged with any tag in this array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, tags

This will be an easy one for any activerecord mavens - though I don't seem to be able to get a working query myself!

I have Articles which have_many Tags through: a Taggings join table.

```
class Article
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end

class Tag
  has_many :articles, through: :taggings
end
```

Given an array of `tag.ids` like `[13, 15, 72, 99]` I want to find all `Articles` that are **not** tagged with any of these tags.

I can select those that are tagged with one or more tags like so:

```
tag_ids = [13, 15, 72, 99]
Article.where(:tags => {:id => tag_ids})
```

But how can I do the inverse?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this and let me know bc I'm not sure: Article.joins(:tags).where('tags.id NOT IN (?)',tags_ids)

Comment: Thanks Ghar. That query still seems to select some Articles that have a tag in the tag_ids array, though most returned do not (310 when limit(500), though 190 with matching tags also returned). Very strange.